# Get values from text/combo boxes on form to different table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-forms, ms-access-data-macro

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String
Private Sub Command208_Click()
strSQL = "INSERT INTO PKR([Claim Number],[WANDFNF],[WANDOUP],[WANDEA]) VALUES ([Forms]![Form Level].[Form]![Claim Number],[Forms]![Form Level].[Form]![Wand_cmb1],[Forms]![Form Level].[Form]![Wand_cmb2],[Forms]![Form Level].[Form]![Wand_txt2])"
strSQL1 = "INSERT INTO PKR([TranFNF],[TranOUP],[TranEA]) VALUES ([Forms]![Form Level].[Form]![Tran_cmb1],[Forms]![Form Level].[Form]![Tran_cmb2],[Forms]![Form Level].[Form]![Tran_txt2])"
strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO PKR([DRFNF],[DROUP],[DREA]) VALUES ([Forms]![Form Level].[Form]![DR_cmb1],[Forms]![Form Level].[Form]![DR_cmb2],[Forms]![Form Level].[Form]![DR_txt2])"
 
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL1
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False8
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL2
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Here i have build a button command_208 to get data from text/combo boxes on a form to different table PKR.
I am able to get data for 1st query but not getting any data for the strSQL1 & strSQL2.

Comment: You want to insert 3 records? Why do you need to use VBA instead of BOUND form? Really only need one pair of SetWarnings. Why does the last one show `False8`? Leave warnings on for testing and see what message you get.

Comment: Thanks braX, but i was trying to get these values to diffrent tables and now i am able to. BTW False8 was typing error :P

Comment: "to different tables" - but each SQL references same table.